# Is there an ideal time between paint coats?

Tags: painting, paint

I have been repainting my house and wondering about recoat times.

For instance, the gloss I am using states touch dry in 2h, recoat in 6h and fully cured in 24h (depending on temperature, humidity, etc).  Obviously I should wait at least 6h before the next coat.  But is it any better (or worse) to wait longer, e.g. 48h? It seems plausible that the next coat might bond better if the first one is not fully cured, but is this true?

Comment: Follow the instructions on the tin - RTFM. If you leave one coat to cure too long then the second coat can come off easily, and seen this.

Comment: If you wait beyond the cure time of gloss paint then you need to scuff up the entire wall with sandpaper that's 200 grit or finer so that the new coat can adhere properly. Washing down the wall with denatured alcohol would also have the same effect but make sure you have good ventilation.

Comment: It depends on the paint, read instructions. I once used a automotive paint that said " recoat within 24 hours or wait 7 days", so different paints are different.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus are you telling me I don't need to sand if I recoat before full cure? That's hours of my life I'll never get back...

Comment: No specific instructions on this paint, just looking for general guidelines

Comment: Correct. Also, if the existing wall was glossy then you should have sanded it before the first new coat.

Answer (score 2):

The different dry times listed on paint are really what you need to know in this situation.  The "dry to touch" time means that you can let people back in the area and they won't accidentally get wet paint on them, but that's about all it means.

When you recoat paint too early, the new coat will actually re-wet the previous coat, and your coverage or the paint's hiding ability (hiding stains/colors under the paint) will go down.  Two coats will end up actually being like 1.5 coats or less in some situations.  Not what you want.

So, that's where the recoat time comes in.  At this point, the paint is dry enough that a new layer of paint will not fully re-wet the first layer, but it hasn't been so long that there will be adhesion issues.  This is the optimal time to put on another coat, but its not an exact science.  The time will need to be adjusted based on temperature and air flow, but its a good starting point.

The last time is a "full cure" and after that time has elapsed, the next coat might not stick as well, or at the very least, might not cover very well if you're using a glossier sheen.  Try to recoat before this time has elapsed.  One other note, with a latex/acrylic paint, it might say that "full cure" is 24 hours, but that is rarely true.  It might be something like 75% cured, and 100% can take weeks or longer (to reach its full hardness and durability).